# XMLTask to alter this elements text content

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

Considering the following XML, how can I use the Ant task `XMLTask` to change bar using foo as a filter if there many items like this with different names.

```
<string name="foo">bar</string>
<string name="another">a value goes here</string>
<string name="somethingelse">some other value</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we'll assume your xml is actually valid and include a top-level element, e.g.

```
<mydocument>
  <string name="foo">bar</string>
  <string name="another">a value goes here</string>
  <string name="somethingelse">some other value</string>
</mydocument>
```

Then, the XPath expression for your specific `<string>` elements is:
`//string[@name='foo']` (and for the value, add `\text()`.

Finally, the XmlTask becomes, for instance:

```
<xmltask source="source.xml" dest="target.xml">
  <replace path="//string[@name='foo']/text()" withText="foobar"/>
</xmltask>
```